# Get property names via reflection of a COM object

Tags: c#, reflection, com, properties

How can I read out all property names via reflection of an COM Object in C#?
I know how to get the property if I know the name.

```
comObject.GetType().InvokeMember("PropertyName", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, comObject, null);
```

but what is when I want to dump all properties?

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();
```

This way didn't work with Com-Objects. If I do a GetMembers() I get these Members:

```
Name: GetLifetimeService
Name: InitializeLifetimeService
Name: CreateObjRef
Name: ToString
Name: Equals
Name: GetHashCode
Name: GetType
```

regards Chris

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, because you are already providing the answer. `GetProperties` will return all properties of a type.

Comment: If the COM Object implements `IDispatch` you could try casting it to `System.Reflection.IReflect` and use it's methods to inspect the object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You got the members of the __ComObject class, the underlying .NET class for an RCW.

COM has a wee bit support for reflection, as long as the COM coclass implements IDispatch, the Automation interface.  Not unusual, it is the interface that scripting languages use to make calls.  IDispatch.GetIDsOfNames() is always implemented, but you have to know the name of the member up front.  IDispatch.GetTypeInfo() gives access to the type library for the coclass, but isn't always implemented.  Translation of type library info to metadata is an imperfect art, the core reason why .NET wants you to do this upfront with Tlbimp.exe.  If you want to pursue a runtime approach then you'll probably benefit from the source for the managed version of Tlbimp, [available here](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/17579).

Doing this up front at build time is always best, you do so by adding a reference to the type library (usually embedded in the executable file) or by running Tlbimp.exe yourself.  Now you got a .NET interop wrapper class that has all of the members of the underlying COM coclass and interfaces.  At which point you probably don't need reflection anymore :)

Answer (score 13):

I've just published a CodeProject article about how to do [Reflection with IDispatch-based COM objects](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/523417/Reflection-with-IDispatch-based-COM-objects).  The article provides a small C# `DispatchUtility` helper class that's easy to include in other projects.  Internally, it uses a custom declaration of IDispatch and .NET's TypeToTypeInfoMarshaler to convert IDispatch's ITypeInfo into a rich .NET Type instance.

In your example, you could call `DispatchUtility.GetType(comObject, true)` to get back a .NET Type instance, which you could then call GetProperties or GetMembers on.

I've also provided a version of the DispatchUtility source code on StackOverflow in a response to [How to enumerate members of COM object in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14208030/1882616)

Comment: Thank you for the awesome article. I tried using it but facing a problem. I am getting error: "type library was exported from a clr assembly and cannot be re imported"
I am using Activator.createInstance to create the object. The tool for which I am creating the COM object is Tibco Spotfire v6.5.2
Could you please help. Thanks

Comment: @Bill Menees, could your helper class be used in [PowerShell to create instance of COM object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945859/use-powershell-to-create-instance-of-com-object)?