# Type.GetProperties() for COM object showing inconsistent behavior

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to list all the run time properties of Microsoft Word "Shape" object. I first got the type of com object using QueryInterface and then call GetProperties(). This worked well when i was using it in console application, I got COM object type as "Shape" and returned 70 properties of that. When same code I put behind a winform button click, I get only 1 property. Is there any specific reason for this or any other way to achieve this.

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape tbx = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 
        leftPosition + 5, topPosition + 5, 100, 50);

    Type objType = tbx.GetType();

    if (objType.IsCOMObject)
    {
        objType = GetTypeForComObject(tbx);
    }

    PropertyInfo[] properties2 = objType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);


private Type GetTypeForComObject(object wordComObject)
    {

        IntPtr iunkwn = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(wordComObject);
        System.Reflection.Assembly wordAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Word.Application));
        Type[] wordTypes = wordAssembly.GetTypes();            
        foreach (Type currType in wordTypes)
        {
            Guid iid = currType.GUID;
            if (!currType.IsInterface || iid == Guid.Empty)
            {                    
                continue;
            }
            IntPtr ipointer = IntPtr.Zero;
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.QueryInterface(iunkwn, ref iid, out ipointer);

            if (ipointer != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // yeah, that’s the one we’re after
                return currType;
            }
        }           
        return null;
    }
```

I tried also using GetFields() and then Invoke() which also didn't work. Also putting this job in backgroundworker thread also didn't help.

Comment: What property is it returning?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: what is `GetTypeForComObject`? and waht is `obj`?

Comment: possible duplicate [get-property-names-via-reflection-of-a-com-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615019/get-property-names-via-reflection-of-a-com-object)

Comment: It's returning "Fill" property only. @Grundy, I 've seen this thread but it didn't solve this problem. Moreover, DispatchUtility method takes close to 1 minute to query for the type of object . That's why I used QueryInterface. Obj is actual "tbx" object which I mentioned in snippet.

Comment: Added implementation for GetTypeForComObject