# Excel reading gives a [system.__comobject] in return

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, import-from-excel

In my WPF application I'm trying to read the excel file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. It was working fine. But suddenly it gives [system.__comobject] rather than excel object. I have no idea what happen now. Your help will save my all day. Thanks. My code as follows,

```
 public class ReadExcelDataModel
{
    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook workbook;
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
    Excel.Range range;
    private int row = 0;

public ResponceModel ReadWorksheet(string FileName, string FilePath, ResponceModel ResponceResult)
    {
        Error error = new Error();
        //workbook = Excel.Workbook;
        //worksheet = new Excel.Worksheet();
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        List<Task<ResponceModel>> TaskList = new List<Task<ResponceModel>>();
        try
        {
            string excelFilePath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", FilePath, FileName);
            workbook =  excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath);
            for (int i = 1; i <= workbook.Sheets.Count; i++)
            {
                worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[i];
                ResponceResult.SheetName = worksheet.Name;
                ResponceResult.dataTable.Add(SwitchTheTables(worksheet, ResponceResult).TempDataTable);
            }
            workbook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            excelApp.Quit();
            ResponceResult.Responce = "OK";
            return ResponceResult;
        }
        catch
        {
            error.ErrorCode = 405;
            error.ErrorDescription = string.Format("The worksheet name not found.");
            ResponceResult.Responce = "Error";
            ResponceResult.ErrorList.Add(error);
            return ResponceResult;
        }

    }
}
```

workbook =  excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath); in here workbook take the [system.__comobject] as value. Previously it got the excel object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772156/how-return-the-type-of-a-system-comobject-in-system-type-in-c-sharp go through this

Comment: My crystal ball says that you did something wonky to try to get the very wrong `//workbook = Excel.Workbook;` statement to compile.  Like adding another variable named *workbook* of type *object*.  Use source control to rewind back to the previously working version.

Comment: Is there anything can affect because of Office package? I'm using office 2013.